# CanvasJS Pie Chart - Preparing a JS Array to Hold Data

Tags: pie-chart

I can successfully render a canvasJS pie chart using static data hard-coded within a js array like this:

```
// Hardcoded data - this will successfully render a pie chart
var dps = [{ y: 1, indexLabel: "Writing" }, { y: 0, indexLabel: "External Collaboration" }, { y: 0, indexLabel: "Ready for Edit" }, { y: 0, indexLabel: "Editing" }, { y: 0, indexLabel: "Ready for Review" }, { y: 0, indexLabel: "In Pink Team" }, { y: 0, indexLabel: "In Gold Team" }, { y: 1, indexLabel: "In Red Team" }, { y: 0, indexLabel: "Final Versions" }]
```

However, I need to simply reference an array already populated. I am populating an array from a table on the page. I can’t understand why it won’t work because when I convert the array to string and print, everything is formatted correctly.

Below is the link to my jsfiddle example code.

[JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/cgtrman/J4YLV/10/)

Line 18 is where I think the issue is.

```
// S/B formatted like this: {  y: 10, indexLabel: "Writing (1)" }
dps.push(['\{ y: ' + Number(value) + ', indexLabel: \"' + key + ' (' + value + ')\" \}' ]);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
dps.push({ y: Number(value), indexLabel: key + '(' + value + ')'});
```

I was not building the array the right way. I was putting text elements in it where I needed to put objects in it.